# How to open package list in emacs

Tags: help, list-packages

The question is simple as Opening package list in emacs on macOS, I knew everywhere is **Type `M-x list-packages` to open the package list.**, but it's just not working for me

0. `brew install emacs`
1. Start emacs
   [image]
2. Then goes to
   [image]
3. Run `M-x list-packages`, I will take it slowly, first `M-x`, it turns
   [image]
4. Then `l`
   [image]
5. I don't think anymore actions need to be taken by far

Strong learning curve, hard to get started for software engineer who has worked several years, I was wondering is this normal?

Comment: No, not normal: already with `M-x`, the response is unexpected. How do you type `M-x`? What does `C-h c M-x` say?

Comment: What @NickD said. And say in the question what your Emacs version is (`M-x emacs-version`). Thx.

Comment: Thank you all, somehow I found the right way to open package list, It is `ESC-x`, press and hold `ESC` then hit `x`, just like press and hold `Option` on macOS then hit `x`, how am I supposed to know it was `ESC-x` rather than `Option-x` since everywhere is `M-x`. thank you